# In a $3$-D vector space, does a vector $R$ being perpendicular to $A$, $B$, $C$ imply that $A$, $B$, $C$ are coplanar?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, 3d, vector-fields

> In $3$-D vector space, If there's a vector $R$ which is given to be perpendicular to three others vectors $A , B , C$.
> Then can just this statement imply that vectors $A ,B ,C$ must be coplanar?

for Eg : Given info was
$R\cdot A=0$
$$
|R\times B|=|R||B| 
$$
$$
|R\times C|=|R||C|
$$
And then it was asked to find value of $[A B C ]$

Answer given was $0$.

Can anyone explain the reason behind this conclusion?

Comment: (Please try to use mathjax in the future)

Comment: Does $[ABC]$ mean $A\cdot(B\times C)$?

Comment: Well, $R=\vec0$ is orthogonal to any set of vectors, not necessarily coplanar. If you restrict $R\ne0$, then the statement is true. Let $R=(r_x,r_y,r_z)$. Then vector $(x,y,z)$ is orthogonal to $R\iff R\cdot(x,y,z)=0\iff r_xx+r_yy+r_zz=0$ i.e. $A,B,C$ all lie in the same plane $(r_x,r_y,r_z).(x,y,z)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

If $|R \times B| = |R||B|$ and $|R \times C| = |R||C|$ this would imply that $R || (B \times C)$ or $|R| = 0$

Since you know that $R.A = 0$, this would imply that $A.(B\times C) = 0$

The only case that would not be covered here is if $B,C$ are collinear. In that case $B\times C$ is $\vec{0}$, so it would still result in the value being 0